# USB ports have completely stopped working

Tags: 16.04, usb

Every USB port has stopped working on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I executed `lsusb` in terminal and was prompted with the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have a look in the BIOS / set-up, sometimes there is an option to disable USB ports - make sure it's off.

Comment: What's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 USB` and `sudo dmesg | grep -i -e '[uoex]hci' -e usb`? See [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) if you don't know how. And could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it will help you: 
Open terminal, type:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

To

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force irqpoll"
```

Save and close the file.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot.

[Source on ubuntugeek.com](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-usb-stops-working-problem-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved me. I'd already pictured myself reinstalling the whole system.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but i have tried Step number (4) in this link (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-usb-device-port-linux/) and works fine with me.

Comment: Don't use this!! This destroyed my grub entry and I could not boot anymore!!! DON'T USE THIS!!!

Comment: Legend! This had been bugging me for ages. Your fix worked perfectly! Cheers.

Comment: @AhmedMousa, your step (4) is "reboot". Writing it out saves people time.

Comment: i dont understand what forcing acpi force irqpoll means but i assume it refreshes the usb devices somehow.. fixed my issues

Answer (score 0):

For GIGABYTE-970A-UD3P I had to do something similar what ozcyto recommended in [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
```

Then (preferably in a new terminal window) run this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your PC and it should work.