# Not recognising usb storage and phones

Tags: usb, usb-drive, portable

I've just upgraded to ubuntu 18.04, i wanted to copy some files from my pendrive but my laptop which runs on Ubuntu is not recognising the pendrive. Nothing happens when i insert the pendrive. I thought maybe the ports are dead but when I plugging in my android phone, it was charging but there was no option on my phone to switch from charging mode to storage mode. So I think the problem is with Ubuntu. What to do? Please help, i'm being so frustrated with continuous issues like this in Ubuntu. Everyday something new comes up and makes my whole day wasted searching on google for solution.

Comment: I am sorry, that you are quite unhappy with ubuntu. Since i switched to Linux in general, i am very excited about this OS. Most things actl work out of the box, where in windows i would need to search for drivers instead. To find solutions for your problems i suggest you do always do an `lspci -knn` to get most improtant information for your google search. Also `dmesg -w` and `lsusb` might be helpfull in this case. Do `dmesg -w` and plug in your device. Its output will show a lot of usefull information for troubleshooting. After that edit your question and copy&paste the outputs

Comment: You can also watch the log entries as they happen with `journalctl --follow`, and read `man journalctl`

Comment: Maybe try https://askubuntu.com/questions/824454/usb-ports-have-completely-stopped-working