# Wifi Adapter, Bluetooth Adapter and Sound is not working after Nvidia Software Update

Tags: wireless, nvidia, usb

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (as second OS with Windows) and today when I switch to Ubuntu my second screen was not working. I used the solution from this thread [External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04) and it worked. After that something odd happened.

I am using TPlink Wifi Adapter and it is not working. When I type lsusb in terminal I can see the device (same thing for Bluetooth Stick) but I cannot connect to internet. In network options I cannot see Wifi option. USB port is working (I tried with External HDD) and everything works in Windows. I tried to connect my phone via USB and it worked but I could not share internet. I tried this [USB ports have completely stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824454/usb-ports-have-completely-stopped-working) but it did not work.
Also sound is not working and only output there is "Dummy".

I am completely stuck. I cannot connect to internet so I cannot update anything (ethernet is not an option in this case and sharing mobile internet did not work).

I have no idea to solve this problem. If anyone can give me a hint I would be so grateful.

Output of:

```
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status

dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-27-generic' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your links aren't working. Please [edit] the question and correct that or, even better, describe what you actually did.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I updated the links and the result of the command chili555 asked. Thank you.

Comment: I believe the answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388279/ubuntu-network-error-after-changes-additional-drivers-software-updates/1388288#1388288

Comment: It worked. The only thing: ' sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.13.0.27-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-extra-5.13.0.27-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-modules-extra-5.13.0.27-generic' '                  But I can still use with previous kernel

Comment: Here it is:https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-27-generic Did you run `sudo apt update` first?

Comment: Yes I did. After I did it twice it worked. Everything is okay now. Thank you so much, you are the best

Comment: The answer I linked is now accepted and upvoted so I will mark your question as a duplicate. Glad it's working!