# Ubuntu network error after changes additional drivers (software & updates)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, internet

For some reason i haven't no sound card detected in ubuntu general settings, so i decided to change the additional drivers from Software and updates.

It was the first option chosen (Using NVIDIA driver metapckage from nvidia-driver-390 (proprietary, tested) and i changed to the second option (Using X.Org X server Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source))

After that i restart the computer but this error oquered:

No wifi-adapter is detected so i cannot restore the changes.

The computer has also an ethernet port so i will try with ethernet cable, and i will post the result.

Edit: I plugged in the cable but no internet connection is established.

Edit2: I have a windows 10 os as dual boot. I notice this, but i don't know if can be helpful in this situation.

Edit3: I found a solution but it didn't work at all.

First, i run `apt-get download nvidia-driver-390` command from another pc.

Second, i `cd` to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and copy all `*nvidia*.deb` files into a usb stick.

Third i boot up from windows partition in the computer that i have not no internet and i copy all the files i copy to usb stick into windows desktop folder.

Finally i tried to run the the .deb files from ubuntu partition but the installation process is in pending status for some time (>3 minutes).

The files i downloaded from the other pc are:

- libnvidia-cfg1-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- libnvidia-common-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_all.deb
- libnvidia-compute-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- libnvidia-compute-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
- libnvidia-decode-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- libnvidia-decode-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
- libnvidia-encode-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- libnvidia-encode-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
- libnvidia-fbc1-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- libnvidia-fbc1-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
- libnvidia-gl-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- libnvidia-gl-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
- libnvidia-ifr1-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- libnvidia-ifr1-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_i386.deb
- nvidia-compute-utils-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- nvidia-dkms-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- nvidia-driver-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- nvidia-kernel-common-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- nvidia-kernel-source-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- nvidia-prime_0.8.17.1_all.deb
- nvidia-settings_470.57.01-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
- nvidia-utils-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
- xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390_390.144-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb

I don't know if there is any dependency order or there is an internet dependency.

Edit: The result of `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` command is:

dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-27-generic' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (=dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.

Any solution expect this: backup the important files and reinstall ubuntu 21.10 LTS?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: Done as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please interrupt the boot process to get the GRUB menu to boot into an earlier kernel version, perhaps 5.13.0-25. https://www.pcsuggest.com/enter-grub-menu-on-single-boot-ubuntu-system/

While booted into -25 where, we assume, networking is working as expected, do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-27-generic
```

Reboot.

Comment: Works! Thanks!!!