# Laptop does not work anymore after attempting fix for non working USB port

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, bios

I have tried to fix my non working USB port according to the first answer in [USB ports have completely stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824454/usb-ports-have-completely-stopped-working)

I have Ubuntu 20.04

However after the reebot noting works anymore. When I start the laptop I get the following:

[image]

I never got this before. The laptop was always booting with Ubuntu right away.

When I select Ubuntu I get the following and then nothing works anymore:

[image]

When I select ' Advanced options for Ubuntu' I can select

1. Ubuntu with Linux 5.13.0-1028-oem
2. Ubuntu with Linux 5.13.0-1028-oem ( recovery mode)
3. Ubuntu with Linux 5.13.0-1026-oem
4. Ubuntu with Linux 5.13.0-1026-oem ( recovery mode)
5. Ubuntu with Linux 5.13.0-27-generic
6. Ubuntu with Linux 5.13.0-27-generic ( recovery mode)

Shall I select one if the recovery modes? Or will my data then get lost???

Please help!! What can I do to fix everything?? I need help since I need my laptop to give a talk soon!

Comment: Booting to recovery in GRUB is not going to cause data loss.  But you should always have backups anyway because data loss can happen at any time.  Booting recovery will allow you to go back into the file you changed and change it back.  Since you know exactly what you did that caused the problem, it should be easy to fix by undoing it

Comment: Which recovery mode shall I select? 5.13.0-1028 or 5.13.0-1026 or 5.13.0-27 ?? Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: Did you make a change to grub and then had this problem? If so you may not be able to boot to recovery mode. But do not despair, this can be fixed using a live usb.

Comment: Yeah I did this change as in the post that I have linked and then got this problem. What do you mean with live USB?

Comment: I also found this: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.linuxtechi.com/boot-ubuntu-20-04-rescue-emergency-mode/amp/. Maybe that's the way to go?

Comment: Pick whichever works. If none work, then use a live session. A live session is when you "Try Ubuntu" from installation media. You will have access to the file system to make the changes you need.

Comment: Ok what I'm trying right now: the selection is on 'ubuntu' then I click 'e'. Then I get rid of the '$vt_handoff' and replace it with 'systemd.unit=rescue.target' then I click F10 but I get the same error. I seems to me that the change that I have made is not saved, since when I repeat ' click e when Ubuntu is selected' I still see  '$vt_handoff' ??

Comment: And for your suggestion: I need Ubuntu on a USB ? How can I get that if my laptop is not working??

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Can you access a root shell prompt?  See: https://askubuntu.com/a/92558 -- It does not matter which kernel version you choose as long as it works. Just pick a working "recovery mode".  You do not need to `e` edit any GRUB options to do this. -- If you want to use a live session then yes you will need a USB with Ubuntu on it to boot a live session. It's a good idea to always have one around because it's a helpful tool for all kinds of situations including recovery. If you don't have one you'll need to use a working computer.

Comment: I cannot boot in recovery mode

Comment: And I also don't have a working computer around

Comment: What happens when you follow the instructions I linked, exactly?  If your system is not bootable and you cannot recover it, then you're going to need to reinstall which will also require an installation DVD or USB.

Comment: I resolved it without any live installation.