# Kernel panic, GNU GRUB super slow & ACPI BIOS Error

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, kernel, acpi

Since a few days I've run into the issue of my GNU GRUB dual boot menu being extremely slow (to the point of almost freezing and accepting no input), and my Ubuntu 20.04 boot resulting in a Kernel panic.

First some specs:

```
Ubuntu 20.04 (dual boot Windows 10)
Linux 5.15.0-46-generic
HP Probook 640 G5/856D
Intel(R) Core i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
8192MB DDR4 RAM
BIOS R72 Ver. 01.05.03 04/27/2020
GNU GRUB 2.04
Intel Core i5-8265U

Boot is protected by HP Sure Start
```

First issues were the slow GNU GRUB menu, but after waiting through that my Ubuntu setup worked fine and smoothly. I barely use the Windows partition, and have not used it in the past few weeks, so I don't think the issue is coming from there.

Today I noticed my USB ports were no longer working, so I naively followed this answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/824461) on this board, which sets `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force irqpoll"` in `/etc/default/grub`. After rebooting I now got a Kernel panic when trying to boot Ubuntu.

There's various things that seem to go wrong, I snapped a few images of it here:
[image]

Those `ACPI BIOS Error` messages seem related to the `GRUB_CDMLINE_LINUX` stuff I had changed. A few seconds later, it ends with the following:

[image]

Ending with `Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt`

**My main question**: is this worth solving? Or am I basically screwed and should I attempt formatting and a clean install of my OS?

Comment: Btw, I tried running my Ubuntu in recovery mode but that gave the same errors unfortunately.

Comment: Please don't add images. Copy/paste the text from the various log files in /var/log (or open "log viewer" if you want it graphical)  I for one would like to copy/paste parts and search for them ;-)  You probably need the part in the log just before what stars in the 2nd image ;)

Comment: The acpi errors: those are benign and started happening with kernel 5.13 a lot more than before that. Mismatch between kernel and BIOS. Those will get fixed in due time. Your best bet for this is to install 22.04. Will also circumvent the kernel panic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try that! As I wasn't able to get into my OS I had to do it via images, but I understand.